# Почему то PEP8 ругается на недостаток аргумента word

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymorphy2

В общем использую **pymorphy2**, а именно функцию согласования склонения слова и числительного, но оно почему-то ворчит. Возможно, конечно, тупая ошибка, но я не знаю...

Приложил скрин, чтобы было и так понятно, где он спотыкается.

**3 строка**

```
import pymorphy2
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer
bottle = morph.parse('бутылка')
for i in range(100, 0, -1):
    print(f'''В холодильнике {i} {bottle.make_agree_with_number(i).word} кваса.
Возьмем одну и выпьем.
Осталось {i - 1} {bottle.make_agree_with_number(i - 1).word} кваса.''')
```

Ошибка:

```
            bottle = morph.parse('бутылка')
TypeError: parse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не создан *объект* `MorphAnalyzer`, т.е. вы у *класса* вызываете `parse`, а ему для таких финтов нужно 2 параметра `self` и `word`

Просто создайте `MorphAnalyzer`:

```
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
#                             ^^^^
```

Comment: Так и думал, что ошибка будет глупая) Спасибо большое)